# Do activations of untrainable layers occupy GPU memory during training in Tensorflow-GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

We deal with semantic segmentation of large 3D volumes involving dozens of classes, and we often find ourselves unable to begin training (out of memory errors) in some of our larger models with our 12 GB of GPU memory. We think the following question is important for us to ask to help us strategize our training given our GPU memory constraint.

I am working on a two-step training scheme [[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuXgV.png)] for 3D segmentation of 50 classes. Our model involves U-Net architectures modified for our task and built with tf.keras layers.

The first step is pre-training a cleanup network (S1p).

The second step will involve building a full model comprised of two subnetworks (S1 and S2). S1 layers will be loaded from the pre-trained S1p, and these layers will be set to **untrainable**. Meanwhile, S2 will be initialized with random weights.

I understand that during training, activations of all layers need to be kept in memory to solve for back-propagation. But during inference, only activations of layers currently in execution are stored. For my case, because S1 layers are untrainable and only weights in S2 need training, does Tensorflow know that S1 layer activations do not need to be kept in GPU memory during training?

Thank you.

Version details:

python=3.9

tensorflow-gpu=2.9.1

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of your architecture? I'm not sure if you can do what you want. I assume you already decreased the batch size. Maybe you should consider decreasing image sizes. As a last point, you can try to use [mixed precision](https://keras.io/api/mixed_precision/) which not only saves memory but time.

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, thank you for your reply. Please see the linked illustration in the post since I am not yet permitted to embed photos as a new member. 
And you are correct to assume that I have reduced batch size and have decreased image sizes to what I feel retains the necessary spatial information. I have taken a look at mixed precision, and I think this is definitely worth investigating further.

Comment: Ok. So you can try to pass all your images through s1, then sabe those outputs to disk and then train only S2 using those saved outputs. So you don't need to have both loaded into memory for training. When S2 training finishes, you can connect both models into a single one and use for inference

Comment: Well, I re-read your question. The answer is no: by default, if GPU is available, tensorflow send all operations to GPU. You can check [this doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu) to send different parts of the model to different devices (GPU, CPU)

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna This is a clever solution, but since I need data augmentation during training, I am afraid that it would take a lot of disk space if I saved multiple S1p outputs from augmented inputs into disk (a single volumetric image is 8 MB). 

However, your suggestion gave me an idea: a custom data generator that will (1) augmented original volumetric data, (2) perform inference with the pretrained S1p model, then (3) return the inference output. The data generator can then be used to train the S2 model. Then, I can connect S1p and S2 to build the full model.